# I want to use rfind() to find the highest index in a str but it returns lowest index

Tags: python, python-2.7, parsing, find

So I am working through a script in Python that opens a file containing email headers that I am parsing to find() a particular set of floating point numbers that I want to use to perform some math functions later.

Here is my code just for fun:

```
fname = raw_input("What is the file name? ")
fhand = open(fname)
total = 0
count = 0
for line in fhand:
    line = line.rstrip()
    linePos = line.rfind('X-DSPAM-Confidence: ')
    if linePos >= 0:
        rnum = line[linePos + 1: (linePos + 1)+7]
        print rnum
        #total += float(rnum)
        #count += 1
    elif linePos == -1:
        continue

#avg = total/count
#print "Average spam confidence: " + avg
```

I am trying to use rfind() to get the highest index in the str i am searching for in order to slice[] the floating point numbers I want from the line being read.

My out put on a test print I ran to see where my rfind() is putting me is going like this:

```
What is the file name? mbox-short.txt
-DSPAM-
-DSPAM-
-DSPAM-
-DSPAM-
-DSPAM-
-DSPAM-
-DSPAM-
-DSPAM-
-DSPAM-
-DSPAM-
-DSPAM-
-DSPAM-
-DSPAM-
-DSPAM-
-DSPAM-
-DSPAM-
-DSPAM-
-DSPAM-
-DSPAM-
-DSPAM-
-DSPAM-
-DSPAM-
-DSPAM-
-DSPAM-
-DSPAM-
-DSPAM-
-DSPAM-
```

I am not really interested in any help solving it because I can already do it with the find() method and just adjust for my index as needed to get to the float() data I need to use.

My question is more about rfind() itself and whether or not I am using it correctly and/or have missed something in the documentation regarding its use. When I read the Python2.7 docs it stated that its use is exactly like find() except that it returns the highest index of the str. In my case it didn't, it just acted like find() and returned the lowest index.

The only other thing I thought of next was whether or not it is now deprecated as the Python2.7 docs mentions that some of those methods on that page are being deprecated.

I don't know. Anybody got any input? Or am I just being a noob and getting the rfind() completely wrong???

Comment: It returns the index of the _first_ character of the rightmost match. You are probably confused thinking that it would return the index of the _last_ character of the match (which it won't).

Comment: What he said. Also, those _functions_ in the `string` module are deprecated, but the equivalent  `str.` *methods* are **not** deprecated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you want to extract `0.84725` from a line `X-DSPAM-Confidence: 0.84725` as an example. If so you should replace

```
    rnum = line[linePos + 1: (linePos + 1)+7]
```

with

```
    rnum = line[linePos+len('X-DSPAM-Confidence: '):linePos+len('X-DSPAM-Confidence: ')+7]
```

. `find()` and `rfind()` returns a position of first letter of leftmost or rightmost occurrence, respectively. So you should fix indexing. Then if the line contain one occurrence `find()` and `rfind()` are same.